# How .storyboard file and Interface Builder are related to each other?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

Recently, I've read the "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" - 6th edition" book. And in the first chapter, they said the following:

> A crucial feature of Interface Builder is that it is not a graphical representation of code contained in other files. Interface Builder is an object editor that can create instances of objects and manipulate their properties. When you are done editing an interface, it does not generate code that corresponds to the work you have done. A .storyboard file is an archive of object instances to be loaded into memory when necessary.

It make me confuse and therefore, I can not answer some questions:

1. What are "instances of objects" in "Interface Builder is an object editor that can create instances of objects and manipulate their properties." means? Are they buttons, text fields or image?
2. When I change something in the Interface Builder, I see the .storyboard file changes, too. What do they mean: "Interface Builder is that it is not a graphical representation of code contained in other files"?
3. The last sentence: "A .storyboard file is an archive of object instances to be loaded into memory when necessary". What is "archive of object instances"?, and when they're needed to load into memory?

Can you explain them to me?

Comment: What it means basically is that IB is not a codegen tool. It is a an editor for an archive (a serialized document) of your object graph (controllers included -- for storyboard files). You can better understand this by opening a storyboard or a xib file in a text editor (like textmate or atom). Bear in mind that these files _are_ compiled eventually by Xcode (they are not just loaded and parsed at runtime).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the most of things :D
But I still do not understand what do objects here refer to? are they views objects (button, text field,..) and controllers as you said?

Comment: I don't think there is a restriction for what objects you can instantiate through a storyboard. You can drag an `Object` for example from the components gallery and set its class to a custom class. Think of it as a visual way of initializing & configuring objects (just like you would in code).